# Why application posts on my wall marked as links?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

My application creates posts on user's wall, but it's marked as link. 
I see that other applications doing same thing but for some reason facebook don't mark their posts as links. Tried to find the difference between them and me in graph api explorer, and the only difference is status_type attribute (this is not even documented). Mine set to "shared_story" and in other applications is "app_created_story". Tried to set it manualy but facebook still use shared_story even if I set it to app_created_story

Data from graph api explorer (first is my application)

```
[{
  "id": "100001302536317_168939309896943", 
  "from": {
    "name": "Андрей Реаскович", 
    "id": "100001302536317"
  }, 
  "story": "Андрей Реаскович shared a link.", 
  "story_tags": {
    "0": [
      {
        "id": "100001302536317", 
        "name": "Андрей Реаскович", 
        "offset": 0, 
        "length": 16, 
        "type": "user"
      }
    ]
  }, 
  "picture": "http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBcrRQnipKHB6g6&w=90&h=90&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.jackpotrush.com%2Fimages%2Fviral%2Fgames%2Fjoker_jester.png", 
  "link": "http://apps.facebook.com/jackrush/?ref=bonus-game", 
  "name": "I Won Big on a Bonus Round at Jackpot Rush!", 
  "caption": " ", 
  "description": "I Just Won 200 Coins at a Jackpot Rush Bonus Round and it Feels Amazing!", 
  "icon": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yD/r/aS8ecmYRys0.gif", 
  "actions": [
    {
      "name": "Comment", 
      "link": "http://www.facebook.com/100001302536317/posts/168939309896943"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Like", 
      "link": "http://www.facebook.com/100001302536317/posts/168939309896943"
    }
  ], 
  "privacy": {
    "description": "Only Me", 
    "value": "SELF"
  }, 
  "type": "link", 
  "status_type": "shared_story", 
  "application": {
    "name": "Jackrush Development", 
    "namespace": "jackrush", 
    "id": "434595133235542"
  }, 
  "created_time": "2012-11-12T08:48:18+0000", 
  "updated_time": "2012-11-12T08:48:18+0000", 
  "comments": {
    "count": 0
  }
},


{
  "id": "100001302536317_420171444702936", 
  "from": {
    "name": "Андрей Реаскович", 
    "id": "100001302536317"
  }, 
  "picture": "http://platform.ak.fbcdn.net/www/app_full_proxy.php?app=242829452408559&v=1&size=z&cksum=cd0fa7a15202d05700bf1464fd989d42&src=http%3A%2F%2Fc.cdn.blueshellgames.com%2Fs%2F%3Aac05b878%2Fmonte%2Fi%2Ffeed_story_image-logo_black.png", 
  "link": "http://apps.facebook.com/luckyslotsgame/?action=shareLevelUpReward&posterID=fb%3A100001302536317&k_utag=df3f4636aabab65e&levelUpToken=6553%3AsVFCJmW43zW_Nni9vBB9xg%3D%3D&level=4&refID=fb%3A100001302536317&utm_medium=viral&utm_source=levelUp", 
  "name": "First 5 Clickers get 150 Free Coins!", 
  "caption": "Андрей just reached level 4 and is giving away 150 Free Coins to celebrate!", 
  "description": "Play the best slots on Facebook! Get free chips daily! Unlock new slot machines and new bonus games! Don't miss out, play now!", 
  "icon": "http://photos-d.ak.fbcdn.net/photos-ak-snc7/v85006/51/242829452408559/app_2_242829452408559_9481.gif", 
  "actions": [
    {
      "name": "Comment", 
      "link": "http://www.facebook.com/100001302536317/posts/420171444702936"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Like", 
      "link": "http://www.facebook.com/100001302536317/posts/420171444702936"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Claim BONUS Coins", 
      "link": "http://apps.facebook.com/luckyslotsgame/?action=shareLevelUpReward&posterID=fb%3A100001302536317&k_utag=df3f4636aabab65e&levelUpToken=6553%3AsVFCJmW43zW_Nni9vBB9xg%3D%3D&level=4&refID=fb%3A100001302536317&utm_medium=viral&utm_source=levelUp"
    }
  ], 
  "privacy": {
    "description": "Public", 
    "value": "EVERYONE"
  }, 
  "type": "link", 
  "status_type": "app_created_story", 
  "application": {
    "name": "Lucky Slots", 
    "namespace": "luckyslotsgame", 
    "id": "242829452408559"
  }, 
  "created_time": "2012-11-12T08:13:25+0000", 
  "updated_time": "2012-11-12T08:13:25+0000", 
  "comments": {
    "count": 0
  }
}]
```

Comment: There was a discussion about this in the FB developers group on Facebook lately, and it suggested that when using actions links on your post, this behavior does not occur. There are also bug reports for this already, f.e. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/138798476259001

Comment: possible duplicate of [Post a feed with a link without 'shared as link'](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11782087/post-a-feed-with-a-link-without-shared-as-link)

Comment: It's not documented _well_, but there is a mention of the status_type attribute here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post